# Finding the file name in a directory with a pattern

Tags: shell, unix

I need to find the latest file - `filename_YYYYMMDD` in the directory DIR.

The below is not working as the position is shifting each time because of the spaces between(occurring mostly at file size field as it differs every time.)

please suggest if there is other way.

```
report =‘ls -ltr $DIR/filename_* 2>/dev/null | tail -1 | cut -d “ “ -f9’
```

Comment: `ls -1t | head -n 1`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWK to cut the last field . like below

```
report=`ls -ltr $DIR/filename_* 2>/dev/null | tail -1 | awk '{print $NF}'`
```

Cut may not be an option here

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you want to loop though each file in the directory and file the largest `'YYYYMMDD'` value and the filename associated with that value, you can use simple [**POSIX parameter expansion with substring removal**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06) to isolate the `'YYYYMMDD'` and compare against a value initialized to `zero` updating the `latest` variable to hold the largest `'YYYYMMDD'` as you loop over all files in the directory. You can store the `name` of the file each time you find a larger `'YYYYMMDD'`.

For example, you could do something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
name= 
latest=0
for i in *; do 
    test "${i##*_}" -gt "$latest" && { latest="${i##*_}"; name="$i"; }
done
printf "%s\n" "$name"
```

**Example Directory**

```
$ ls -1rt
filename_20120615
filename_20120612
filename_20120115
filename_20120112
filename_20110615
filename_20110612
filename_20110115
filename_20110112
filename_20100615
filename_20100612
filename_20100115
filename_20100112
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ name=; latest=0; \
> for i in *; do \
>   test "${i##*_}" -gt "$latest" && { latest="${i##*_}"; name="$i"; }; \
> done; \
> printf "%s\n" "$name"
filename_20120615
```

Where the script selects `filename_20120615` as the file with the greatest `'YYYYMMDD'` of all files in the directory.

Since you are using only tools provided by the shell itself, it doesn't need to spawn subshells for each pipe or utility it calls.

Give it a test and let me know if that is what you intended, let me know if your intent was different, or if you have any further questions.